# Clean up api for groups of attributes in active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, struct

Given I have the following models:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :verb
  belongs_to :noun
  ...
end

class Verb < ActiveRecord::Base; end
  has_many :rules
end

class Noun< ActiveRecord::Base; end
  has_many :rules
end
```

And, because I work with verb+noun as a pair, I have the following helper (not-persistable):

```
class Phrase < Struct.new(:verb, :noun); ...; end
```

How can I turn this:

```
phrase = Phrase.new(my_verb, my_noun)

# sadface
Rule.create(verb: phrase.verb, noun: phrase.noun)
Rule.where(verb_id: phrase.verb.id).where(noun_id: phrase.noun.id)

# into this?
Rule.create(phrase: phrase)
Rule.where(phrase: phrase)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't think of this right away. I guess maybe the associations through me off. It's easy though.

To clean up `create` I just need to create a virtual attribute on `Rule`

```
def phrase=(phrase)
  self.verb = phrase.verb
  self.noun = phrase.noun
end

# which allows me to
Rule.create(phrase: my_phrase)
```

To clean up the arel `where` query, I just need to create a scope on rule.

```
def self.with_phrase(phrase)
  where(verb: p.verb, noun: p.noun)
end

# which allows me to
Rule.with_phrase(phrase)
```

Answer (score 1):

T avoid Rule.where(...).where(...) you can create a scope:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_phrase, lambda { |p| where(verb: p.verb, noun: p.noun) }
end
```

And then:

```
Rule.with_phrase( Phrase.new(my_verb, my_noun) )
```

Comment: Yea, +1. I don't know why I confused myself on this one. Added an answer which solves both problems.